# Ascii package NBSP and NUL symbols

Tags: symbols

The following does not work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ascii}

\begin{document}
$\NBSP$
$\NUL$
\end{document}
```

The error under `pdflatex` and `xelatex` is

```
Undefined control sequence \NBSP
Undefined control sequence \NUL
```

The symbols `\NBSP` and `\NUL` are listed by the Latex Comprehensive Symbol List (LCSL), but there seem to be no trace of these symbols in either the `ascii` package documentation, or in the `ascii.sty` style file (MikTeX 2.9).

Which symbols is LCSL showing?

Comment: What makes you think they are math mode symbols? Just remove the `$` characters.

Comment: Problem persists without $'s.

Comment: Works fine here, what happens for you? Do you get an error, do you get no output ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `\NBSP` is

```
% ascii.sty, line 90:
\def\NBSP{{\asciifamily\char"A0}\xspace}
```

and this implies that `\NBSP` will definitely not work in math mode. Indeed, if you try it, you'll see, in the `.log` file

```
Missing character: There is no <A0> in font cmr10!
```

Without `$`'s it works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ascii}

\begin{document}
\NBSP
\NUL
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `ascii.sty` file which comes with my MikTeX 2.9 does not contain a definition for `\NSBP` or `\NUL` at all. But it contains other commands, and is dated 10 July 1993 (version 1.0). Perhaps you have a newer version?

Comment: @Kaba ``2006/05/30 v2.0 Package `ascii.sty'``

Comment: @Kaba The version on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ascii/?lang=en) is apparently not in MikTeX.

Comment: @Kaba Complain with MiKTeX

Comment: Reported the [issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2472/).